# PDO Mysql Syntax error 1064

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I run the following code:

```
$conn = new PDO(....);
.... pdo attributes ...

$limitvalue = 0;
$limit = 10;
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT ?, ?");
$sql->bindParam(1, $limitvalue, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(2, $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->execute();
```

And i get:

> Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:
>   Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'NULL, 10' at line 1'

It happens only with this particular query. Everything else is OK.

Btw: I know it may look stupid that i do prepared statements for "in-code" values. But it is just an example. In fact the values are depending on the page number but it doesn't matter here - this query is giving the same error too.

---

If anybody is interested, the PHP version is: **5.3.4RC2** and MySQL's is: **mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a [php bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44639) : PDO ignores the PARAM_INT constant and use the `$limit` and `$limitvalue` variables as string. Which are quoted in the query when bound.

Try using :

```
$sql->bindParam(1, (int)$limitvalue, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sql->bindParam(2, (int)$limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

To force the variables type to int.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works now. But one more question - why the second parameter ($limit) is working fine without the int conversion? I mean that if my SQL query is like `LIMIT X, Y` why only **X** needs the conversion you mentioned (because **Y** works fine)? Does it refer to the bug :)?

Comment: I have no idea. Gotta love those bugs :p.

Comment: This will cause an error. Parameter 2 of `PDOStatement::bindParam()` is passed by reference. The values of `$limitvalue` and `$limit` must be cast to integer and stored in variables (can be the same variables) and then those variables passed. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score -2):

I don't think that the first parameter of the limit in the sql can be NULL. If you just want the first 10 records then use LIMIT 10.

Comment: It isn't NULL - in the code, `$limitvalue = 0`

Comment: I also thought that it may be the problem. I've changed it to 1 but i still got this error. So no, it doesn't matter here.