# MySQL Error 1064 Using LIMIT Clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm having a strange issue running a query via PDO prepared statements that I just can't spot the issue. When running the query manually it works just fine. Here is the code (simplified for conciseness):

```
// Query Parameters
$params = array( 1, 5 );

// Get Products
$query = "SELECT * FROM mydb.Product
          WHERE ProductId >= ?
            AND IsApproved = 1
            AND IsPublic = 1
          LIMIT ?";

// Get Database Instance
$dbh = App\App::getDatabase()->getInstance();

// Prepare Query
if( $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query) )
{
   if( $stmt->execute($params) )
   {
       // Return Records
   }
}
```

Removing the `LIMIT ?` portion from the query returns all results as expected. Instead, when attempting to use the LIMIT and it passes **5** as the value, I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''5'' at line 5

A dump of the **PDOStatement** object after preparation shows:

```
object(PDOStatement)[59]
    public 'queryString' => string 'SELECT * FROM mydb.Product
       WHERE ProductId >= ?
       AND IsApproved = 1
       AND IsPublic = 1
       LIMIT ?'
```

I've tried putting a semicolon at the end of the query but that gives same error. Am I having cerebral flatulence and missing something obvious?

---

**TL;DR;** Why does my prepared statement fail when using the LIMIT clause with a 1064 error?

Comment: because as of this moment, values for `LIMIT` are not yet allowed to be parameterized unless you are using some user defined classes like [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

Comment: Interesting, so my solution here is to manually validate the limit value and place it directly into the query? You should post this as an answer because I am sure many other people are unaware that LIMIT cannot be parameterized!

Comment: anyway, values for `LIMIT` are integers so they are easy to validate `(int)$var`

Comment: @491243 Right, I use the `intval()` function -- but same premise. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this could be a duplication of 
[PDO Mysql Syntax error 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777154/pdo-mysql-syntax-error-1064)

The solution is to bind limit parameter forcing it to be an int instead of a string with a simple (int) cast.

Comment: To add to your answer what 491243 said, PHP's PDO does not support parameterizing queries using the "?" and array of values passed into the `execute` method.

Answer (score 0):

just put (int) before your limit value

Comment: Isn't this what previous answer stated?