# There's an error in my syntax

Tags: php

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET user_surname = 'name', SET user_sprat = '1234567'' at line 3 i

```
    //the query to run
    $sql = "UPDATE user 
            SET    user_firstname    = ?,
            SET    user_surname      = ?,
            SET    user_sprat        = ?,
            SET    user_country      = ?,
            SET    user_telephone    = ?,
            SET    user_mobile       = ?,
            SET    user_contactemail = ?,
            SET    user_introduction = ?
            WHERE  user_id = ? 
                   AND user_enabled=1";

    //run the query
    $database = DatabaseFactory::getFactory()->getConnection();
    $update_profile = $database->prepare($sql);
    $update_profile->execute(array($firstname, $surname, $sprata, $country, $telephone, $mobile, $email, $introduction,Session::get('id')));
```

I get that error, I'm not sure why, any help would be great all my tables are named correctly to my knowledge

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO Mysql Syntax error 1064](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777154/pdo-mysql-syntax-error-1064)

Comment: that isn't how UPDATE works. Please RTFM before posting https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct SQL syntax for an update query is `UPDATE table SET rowA = value, rowB = value` Notice `SET` was mentioned once and commas used to separate the rows.

EG:

```
$sql = "UPDATE user SET
        user_firstname    = ?,
        user_surname      = ?,
        user_sprat        = ?,
        user_country      = ?,
        user_telephone    = ?,
        user_mobile       = ?,
        user_contactemail = ?,
        user_introduction = ?
        WHERE  user_id = ? 
               AND user_enabled=1";
```

Reference:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: Agreed, apologies for this oversight by me