# PHP Limit with session var sql error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error, session-variables

My questions is get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'' at line 1

This piece of code gives me the error:

```
public function toonAlles()
{
    try {
        if (isset($_SESSION["limiet"])) {
            $limitwaarde = $_SESSION["limiet"];
            echo $limitwaarde;
            var_dump($limitwaarde);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM lottogamedata LIMIT :limietwaarde";
            $smt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $smt->bindParam("limietwaarde", $limitwaarde, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        }
        else{
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM lottogamedata";
            $smt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        }

        $smt->execute();
        $lottotabel = $smt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

    return $lottotabel;
}
```

this is where initialize the session:

```
session_start();
$Winkel = Winkel::getEuroInstantie();
Uitvoer::toonKeuzeMenu();
Uitvoer::extraFunctions();
if (isset($_POST["submitTheSpecifyRequest"])){
    helper::voegToegAanDeSessie($_POST["maxNumbers"]);

}
```

this is the submitTheSpecifyRequest button:

```
public static function extraFunctions(){
    ?>
      <form class="form-group" method="post" id="extraOpties">
          <label for="maxNumbers">Limit the results by</label>
          <input name="maxNumbers" class="form-control" id="maxNumbers" type="number" required min="1" value="1">
          <input type="submit" value="Specify your search" class="btn btn-primary" name="submitTheSpecifyRequest" id="submitTheSpecifyRequest"/>
      </form>
    <?php
}
```

Thanks in advance for me helping me out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO Mysql Syntax error 1064](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777154/pdo-mysql-syntax-error-1064)

Comment: If I try that is gives my a Fatal error:  Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in on line 49

Comment: Try doing `$smt->bindParam(":limietwaarde", ...` (with colon in front of `limietwaarde`) [see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php)

Comment: @Steven Yes, that's what one of the comments said also. Try `$limitwaarde = (int)$_SESSION["limiet"];`

Comment: @rickdenhaan thanks it worked!

Comment: @Steven explaining got a bit long for a comment, so I added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO's `bindParam` has a bug, where if you try to bind a string with `PDO::PARAM_INT` it will still actually bind it as a string anyway (with quotes). You need to convert your value to an int yourself:

Note that you cannot cast it to an int in the call to `bindParam` itself, because it expects a reference. By casting inline in the function call you won't have a variable it can reference, so you must cast it to a variable beforehand.

```
// won't work:
$limitwaarde = $_SESSION["limiet"];
$smt->bindParam("limietwaarde", (int)$limitwaarde, PDO::PARAM_INT);

// will work:
$limitwaarde = (int)$_SESSION["limiet"];
$smt->bindParam("limietwaarde", $limitwaarde, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that $limitwaarde is not an int, session stored variables are maybe stored as strings

try :

```
$smt->bindParam(":limietwaarde", intval($limitwaarde), PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: If var_dump($limietwaarde) do that is the result: :string '1' (length=1) is their away to convert it? Are cookies maybe better?

Comment: No, but you put : PDO::PARAM_INT so it is expecting an int

Comment: Session or cookies, it depends on you needs

Comment: If I use this $sql = "SELECT * FROM lottogamedata LIMIT ".$limitwaarde; instead of $sql = "SELECT * FROM lottogamedata LIMIT :limitwaarde"; with bindParam it works? Why wouldn't it work with bindPara?

Comment: I think it won't work because you are using PDO::PARAM_INT and passing a string to bindParam function, you have to parse the string stored in session to use it

Comment: moreover, you should put :limitwaarde you do not forget using : in bindParam function